# Function is not iterating through a generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, iteration, generator

I have a function that has a "for" loop that has to iterate through a generator, but, actually, it doesn't iterate.

```
def join_probabilities(prob_generator, importance):
    probabilities, count = {}, 0
    print('Before the "for" loop')
    for text_probabilities in prob_generator:
        print('In the "for" loop')
```

I've added 2 prints, but when I run the function, I see only the first of them. What may be wrong?

Comment: ```prob_generator``` is empty, so the ```for``` loop is not iterating at all

Comment: Almost certainly, because `prob_generator` is empty.

Comment: We can't really answer without seeing the code that calls this.  That's where the problem lies.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: Make a [mcve].  `prob_generator` is empty, but this code doesn't reproduce the problem without showing the code that creates the generator and calls this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I've found the problem. The generator is empty, and the problem is in creating the generator. But it is already another question.